# Text wrapping in list items

Tags: css, menu

On the follow page:

http://steve.brettatkin.com/Templates/3-column.php

The secondary navigation is overlapping and loosing the indent when the text wraps.

Here is the CSS file:

http://steve.brettatkin.com/inc/css/3-col.css

How do I fix both issues?

Thanks!

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a padding or margin instead of text-indent, if you want the indent to affect all lines (not just the first). The overlap is caused by your `#navigation a { height: 25px; }`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed both issues.  Is there a way to make this work without using a class?  For example, line 112 of the CSS file.  Why can't I do something like: #navigation ul > li > ul > li:hover?  Also, the references seem out of order as well.

Comment: I see just a `}` on line 112. What's wrong with `#navigation ul > li > ul > li:hover`? Does it not work when you try it?

Comment: I'm referring to this: #navigation li:hover .sub-nav  I tried this: #navigation ul > li > ul > li:hover and the hover stops working

Comment: Then maybe you meant `#navigation ul > li:hover > ul > li`?